# dropdown disable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

i try to disable dropdown in table.. like when admin view any new documents and then select value from dropdown i.e aprove/reject when he select and click on button then this dropdown must be disabled and then when amdin again view new documents then in this dropdown must bt enable until admin approve/reject this document .....how i done this ..

here is the code ...

```
protected void Repeater2_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddldrop = e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList4") as DropDownList;
    HiddenField hfDepartmentId = Repeater2.FindControl("hfDepartmentId") as 
        HiddenField;

    if (ddldrop != null && hfDepartmentId != null && hfDepartmentId.Value != 
        string.Empty && hfDepartmentId.Value.Trim() != "3")
    {
        ddldrop.SelectedValue = hfDepartmentId.Value.Trim();
        ddldrop.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

html code

```
 <div class="CSSTableGenerator">
                <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
           id="results">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" 
                  OnItemCommand="Repeater2_ItemCommand"   
                        runat="server" onitemdatabound="Repeater2_ItemDataBound">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <%--<td>


                                </td>--%>
                                <td>
                                    DocumentID
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    DocName
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    File Name
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Document
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Department
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Status

                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                               <%-- <td>

                                    <asp:HiddenField  Id="DocId" runat="server">
                               </asp:Label/>
                                     <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocID")%>



                                </td>--%>
                                <td>
                                    <%--<asp:Label Id="DocId" runat="server">
                          </asp:Label>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 
                                   "DocID")%>--%>
                                    <asp:Label Id="DocId" 
                  text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocID")%>' 
             runat="server">
                                    </asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <asp:Label Id="DocName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocName")%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <asp:Label Id="Uploadfile" runat="server"></asp:Label>

                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 
                                      "Uploadfile")%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <asp:Label Id="DocType" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DocType")%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <asp:Label Id="DepType" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DepType")%>
                                </td>
                             <%--   <td>

                         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#  
                           Eval("ApproveID") %>' Visible = "false" />
                                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,
                                 "ApproveID")%>
                                </td>--%>

                            <td>


                         <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# 
                    Eval("ApproveID") %>' Visible = "false" />
                          <asp:HiddenField ID="hfDepartmentId" runat="server"  
                    Value='<%# Eval("ApproveID") %>' />


                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" 
              EnableViewState="true" class="vpb_dropdown" DataTextField="ApproveType" 
                           DataValueField="ApproveID" AutoPostBack="true" 
                     OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged">
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Pending" selected="selected" Value="3">
                          </asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Approve" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Text="Reject" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                        </table>       

             <asp:Label ID="Supvisor" runat="server" ></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="B
```

Comment: So what is the problem? The code you posted shows that the drop down list is disabled when the `hfDepartmentId` is not equal to `3`, but I am assuming the drop down is becoming enabled again before it should, right?

Comment: yes...but this code not work ... dropdown always enabled...

Comment: @user2931015 Please do not write long run-on sentences. It is really hard to read.

Comment: sorry what do you mean by long run-on sentences?

Comment: @user2931015 - have you put break points in your code to see if the hidden field (`hfDepartmentId`) is being set correctly and more importantly, if it is being overwritten on a post back to the server?

Comment: when i set a breakpoint (hfDepartmentId) shows me null

Comment: and also ddldrop shows me null

Comment: Then it's always enable, if you have a postback then be sure your dropdown source still available.

Comment: in page load ,,,, if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                
              DMSLIB.ApproveType DEP = new DMSLIB.ApproveType();
              Session["a"] = dd.Depdocuments(Convert.ToString(Session["Login2"]), (Convert.ToString(Session["Login3"])));
              Repeater2.DataSource = dd.hrdoc1(Convert.ToInt32(Session["a"]));
              Repeater2.DataBind();

              Manager.Visible = false;
              Director.Visible = false;

                
               
                    }

Comment: Post the content of your `.aspx` page

Comment: @ChrisLively i posted .please check my update question

Answer (score 0):

**update**

Based on the markup you posted, I don't think the statement "it's always null" is correct.

Change your method to be similar to:

```
protected void Repeater2_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ( e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ) 
    {
        DropDownList ddldrop = e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList4") as DropDownList;
        HiddenField hfDepartmentId = Repeater2.FindControl("hfDepartmentId") as HiddenField;

        if (ddldrop != null && hfDepartmentId != null && hfDepartmentId.Value != 
        string.Empty && hfDepartmentId.Value.Trim() != "3")
        {
            ddldrop.SelectedValue = hfDepartmentId.Value.Trim();
            ddldrop.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, this tests to see if the `ItemType` is an actual `Item` or a `Header` row.  If it's a `Header` row then we just want to skip it as there will not be a DropDownList4.

Then go ahead and set your break point inside to see what's going on.

Comment: I would check to make sure your `hfDepartmentId` isn't always null. Doing a FindControl on the actual repeater doesn't make much sense to me. Typically you'd want the hidden field in the item template or outside of the control.